# How to Configure Multiple Gesture Recognizers for Side Menu

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIViewController` that adds other `UIViewController`s as children so that I can use their `view`s to create a menu hierarchy. The following images represent my current interface.

The interface before displaying the menu:

[image: Screenshot of initial view controller]

The interface after displaying the menu:

[image: Screenshot of menu view controller]

The following explains my hierarchy:

In `AppDelegate` I create an instance of `MainContainerViewController` and set it as the `window`'s `rootViewController`. The view controller acts as a container allowing me to add Chile view controllers.

In `MainContainerViewController` I create an instance of `CenterViewController` and add it as the `rootViewController` of an `UINavigationController`. I add the navigation controller as a child view controller, adding the navigation controller's `view` as a subview of `MainContainerViewController`. I also create an instance of `LeftMenuViewController`, adding it as a child view controller and inserting its view below the navigation controller's `view`. This allows me to tap the `UIBarButtonItem` of `CenterViewController` and show the menu by sliding the navigation controller's `view` to the right.

I have added an `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to the navigation controller's `view` which allows me to show the menu by sliding `CenterViewController`'s `view` off to the right.

I have added an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the navigation controller's view which allows me to close the menu by tapping the navigation controller's view.

I want to be able to use an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to allow the user to interactively close the menu similar to how Slack allows, if you're familiar with their mobile UI.

I added the pan gesture recognizer to the navigation controller's `view`, just as I did with the two aforementioned gesture recognizers. However, I can't get the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to play well together. I have tried implementing combinations of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods without success. I feel a little lost with gesture recognizers, and I don't know where to start with trying to get these gesture recognizers to play well.

I have followed Apple's [example](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate#2557364), adapted to my requirements. If the menu is not displayed, then the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` should allow the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to open the menu.

```swift
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if leftMenuState == .hidden {
        if gestureRecognizer == panGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer.view!.isDescendant(of: gestureRecognizer.view!) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**What I expect:**

1. Ability to display menu by using `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`
2. Ability to tap `CenterViewController` and have menu close
3. Ability to pan `CenterViewController` and close menu

**What happens:**

1. Menu is not opened by panning with `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` because `UIPanGestureRecognizer` receives events
2. Menu is opened by `UIBarButtonItem`
3. Menu is closed by `UIBarButtonItem` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`

What do I need to do to enable the intended functionality?